# Is there a tool to convert DAX measures to SQL?

Tags: powerbi, dax, apache-superset

Currently I'm trying to transfer my dashboards from Microsoft Power BI to Apache Superset. I also need somehow to transfer all measures that are used in dashboards. Are there tools to do it in an automatic mode? As far as I understand it, there is no an analogue of DAX in Apache Superset at least for now. Thank you in advance for your help in this matter.

I have been searching for such tools, but haven't found any suitable. I expect to get a tool or a way to fast convert DAX measure formulas to Apache Superset queries.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Seeking recommendations for tools, libraries or other off site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow, please read the [tour] and [help/on-topic] for some guidance on what you can/can't ask here :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Correct, Superset doesn't have something like DAX nor will it -- its approach is to stay out of the data ETL process and focus only on reporting.  Unfortunately building in DAX instead of SQL means it's painful to leave PowerBI.  You will want to re-implement your calculations and data views in a data warehouse platform / in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no tools that helps you migrate dashboards from Power BI to Apache Superset.

There is no even a similar tool that could vaguely resample [PowerQuery](https://www.reddit.com/r/BusinessIntelligence/comments/118gllg/moving_from_power_bi_to_apache_superset/).

You have to recreate all dashboards from scratch.